Programmatically retrieve OWD setting for a custom object
For standard objects, we can get the OWD setting using the Organization object: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm but there is no equivalent to query the setting for custom objects. Looking for a way to get the OWD value to assess visibility of a custom object for all users in an org.

This question is similar to: Private or public read-only Organization Wide Settings for custom object?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Get object sharing setting on Organization-Wide Defaults. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
